# How can I pull data from a website and put it on an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm new to iPhone app development. I was thinking about making a simple app, just for learning purposes. For example, I want to show the scores of sports games (NBA, NFL, NHL, etc.) What would be the easiest way for me to pull that data from, say, http://www.espn.com and display it on my app?

Thanks!

Comment: a [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) probably.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you want to find an RSS Feed, you can find some of ESPN links [here](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/index), once you have an RSS URL, all you have to do is type it between the quotes in the following string.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    NSString * sFeedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,270000,960000"];
    //RSS Feed URL goes between quotes

    NSString * sActualFeed = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sFeedURL] encoding:1 error:nil];

    lblOne.text = sActualFeed;
    NSLog(@"%@", sActualFeed);
}
```

The URL provided is used to get the current weather, which is not what you want, but all you have to do is change that to the RSS Feed URL you want to display.

The Feed will show up in a Label. Of course you have to make it first, I called it lblOne, but you don't need to have a label, you can use NSLog too just to test it out.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be to find data sources that are provided in XML or JSON format, then use the XML or JSON parsing library of your choice to parse and use the data.

If you can't find any data sources like that, you can use an HTML scraping library (or be extra hacky about it and load a UIWebView offscreen and traverse the DOM) but you will most likely have constant problems with it as any time the website changes it can completely break your app. Also parsing HTML usually requires downloading a lot more data than XML or JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

Using Objective C, you can parse an RSS feed or call an API on a remote site (if you have access to that API) which returns a JSON/XML to your app.

There's a similar answer to such a question here - [What's the best way to parse RSS/Atom feeds for an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566078/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-for-an-iphone-application)